# Downloading Nexus artifacts to Jenkins Job workspace

Tags: jenkins, nexus, jobs, artifact

I have an use case where I need to download selected jar files from nexus repository to a Jenkins job workspace and run a program over the downloaded jar files. (I Want to use the **.class** files in the jars)

Is there any Jenkins plugin available for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a build-step in the job, prior to the one doing the actual work
and use a copy (or ftp) command to get the files.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) and embed a script within your Jenkins job